# How to pass an ArrayList to a varargs method parameter?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Basically I have an ArrayList of locations:

```
ArrayList<WorldLocation> locations = new ArrayList<WorldLocation>();
```

below this I call the following method:

```
.getMap();
```

the parameters in the getMap() method are:

```
getMap(WorldLocation... locations)
```

The problem I'm having is I'm not sure how to pass in the WHOLE list of `locations` into that method.

I've tried

```
.getMap(locations.toArray())
```

but getMap doesn't accept that because it doesn't accept Objects[].

Now if I use

```
.getMap(locations.get(0));
```

it will work perfectly... but I need to somehow pass in ALL of the locations... I could of course make keep adding `locations.get(1), locations.get(2)` etc. but the size of the array varies. I'm just not use to the whole concept of an `ArrayList`

What would be the easiest way to go about this? I feel like I'm just not thinking straight right now.

Comment: Beware of [Java automatically converting collections to arguments arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33461138/java-automatically-converting-collections-to-arguments-arrays)

Answer (score 480, accepted):

Source article: [Passing a list as an argument to a vararg method](http://programming.guide/java/passing-list-to-vararg-method.html)

---

Use the [`toArray(T[] arr)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) method.

```
.getMap(locations.toArray(new WorldLocation[0]))
```

---

Here's a complete example:

```
public static void method(String... strs) {
    for (String s : strs)
        System.out.println(s);
}

...
    List<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>();
    strs.add("hello");
    strs.add("world");
    
    method(strs.toArray(new String[0]));
    //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
```

Comment: How costly this operation would be in terms of memory & speed?

Comment: This will not work without a warning if there are further templates involved. E.g. `someMethod(someList.toArray(new ArrayList<Something>[someList.size()]))` will give you a warning that is very annoying if the function is more than a few lines long (because you can either suppress it for the whole function or you have to create the array in an additional step and suppress the warning on the variable you store it.

Comment: Apparently the fastest approach is giving a size of zero rather than the size of the array. In short, it's because the compile-time constant enables the use of an optimized method. https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/

Comment: @JoshM. Java needs a lot of things. ;) I also (coming from a C# background) miss index operators. Working with dictionaries is much more smooth in C# than working with HashMaps in Java.

Comment: @PerLundberg -- Totally agree. Also a primarily C# developer currently working w/Java8. Maybe 10/11 will be better. :-P

Comment: Java 10+ is a bit better with local variable inference, but big changes like value types are still in the planning stage for the language. I really hope we get non-erased generics also some day... :) (also in Java 8 at the moment but moving towards Java 11)

Comment: gaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa more java voodoo.  thanks for this answer!

Comment: This works just fine in Java 8, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Unless you are using a older version of java. I personally opt for:

strs.stream().toArray(String[]::new);

Not that it is fast, but I like the idea that you do not have to use strs.size().

Comment: I got a warning suggesting zero-length arrays are better and stumbled into this:
https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/commit/56cc0e467f7463a5ad4cb00641c914731aa53be7

Answer (score 95):

In Java 8:

```
List<WorldLocation> locations = new ArrayList<>();

.getMap(locations.stream().toArray(WorldLocation[]::new));
```

Comment: this is java voodoo, but better java (8) voodoo.. thanks!

Comment: `locations.toArray(WorldLocations[]::new)` also seems to works since java 11 (Without the `.stream()`)

Comment: @EranMedan toArray works always without stream, regardless of the Version see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: @kaba713 yes, but not the overload that accepts an `IntFunction`, which was added in Java 11 :) https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)

Answer (score 17):

A shorter version of the accepted answer using Guava:

```
.getMap(Iterables.toArray(locations, WorldLocation.class));
```

can be shortened further by statically importing toArray:

```
import static com.google.common.collect.toArray;
// ...

    .getMap(toArray(locations, WorldLocation.class));
```

Comment: This answer worked for me since I wanted an array of `List`s, but couldn't instantiate a generic array in order to use `Array.toArray`.

Comment: * `List.toArray`

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```java
getMap(locations.toArray(new WorldLocation[locations.size()]));
```

or

```java
getMap(locations.toArray(new WorldLocation[0]));
```

or

```java
getMap(new WorldLocation[locations.size()]);
```

`@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` is needed to remove the ide warning.

Comment: 2nd solution is better!

Comment: Third solution gives a blank array, don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is marked as resolved here my **KOTLIN RESOLUTION**

```
fun log(properties: Map<String, Any>) {
    val propertyPairsList = properties.map { Pair(it.key, it.value) }
    val bundle = bundleOf(*propertyPairsList.toTypedArray())
}
```

bundleOf has vararg parameter

Comment: This is a great answer for kotlin, but it is unlikely to help many people since the question is tagged `java`