# Java automatically converting collections to arguments arrays?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I know that the Java "..." array argument syntax can receive as a parameter an array, or just many parameters passed to the method. However, I noticed that it does so for Collections too:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Collection<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    test(objects);
}

public static void test (Object...objects) {
    System.out.println("no compile errors");
}
```

This compiles and runs without me needing to call the `toArray()` method. What is happening behind the scene? Are there additional methods of this "auto-conversion" for this syntax?

BTW, I'm using Java 1.7.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It doesn't convert the collection to an array. It pass the collection itself as the first vararg argument. The test method thus receives an array of one element, and this element is the ArrayList.

This can be found easily by replacing

```
System.out.println("no compile errors");
```

by

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(objects);
```

Or by using a debugger.

Answer (score 4):

A `Collection<Object>` is also an `Object` so when you invoke `test` with

```
Collection<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
test(objects);
```

it will be invoked with a single parameter that is your collection: the method will receive an array having a single element.

Answer (score 4):

What is happening here is that the method receives an array of length 1 containing a single `Collection`.

Most of the time, the signature

```
method(Object... objs)
```

should be avoided, as it will accept *any* sequence of parameters, even primitives as these get auto boxed.