# Convert Kotlin Array to Java varargs

Tags: java, kotlin, interop, kotlin-interop

How can I convert my Kotlin `Array` to a varargs Java `String[]`?

```
val angularRoutings = 
    arrayOf<String>("/language", "/home")

// this doesn't work        
web.ignoring().antMatchers(angularRoutings)
```

[How to pass an ArrayList to a varargs method parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863742/how-to-pass-an-arraylist-to-a-varargs-method-parameter)

Answer (score 565, accepted):

There’s the **spread operator** which is denoted by `*`.

 The spread operator is placed in front of the array argument:

```
antMatchers(*angularRoutings)
```

For further information, see the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs):

> When we call a `vararg`-function, we can pass arguments one-by-one, e.g. `asList(1, 2, 3)`, or, if we already have an array and want to pass its contents to the function, we use the spread operator (prefix the array with `*`):

Please note that the spread operator is only defined for arrays, and cannot be used on a list directly. When dealing with a list, use e.g.`toTypedArray()` to transform it to an array:

```
 *list.toTypedArray()
```

Comment: And how to convert back?

Comment: @Iacas What do you mean by "convert back"? A `vararg` expects individual elements, and `*array` is the Kotlin way to say "treat this array as individual elements for that purpose". Within the `vararg`-function the `vararg` parameter will be an array anyway. To convert individual elements to an array you can use `arrayOf(...)`, but you don't need that in this case.

Comment: Note that this has a very high-performance penalty. https://sites.google.com/a/athaydes.com/renato-athaydes/posts/kotlinshiddencosts-benchmarks check Varargs, or https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/exploring-kotlins-hidden-costs-part-2-324a4a50b70#da53

Comment: Is there any way to avoid using spread operator and pass some array or list to a method that accepts `vararg`?

Comment: @DarioSeidl He means: What if we have varargs of string, and we wish to pass to a function that expects an array of strings?

Comment: @SimonNinon is right,  `someVarargMethod(*myList.toTypedArray())` work fine