# How to pass a kotlin collection as varagrs?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, kotlin

At first glance it is needed just convert collection to array and pass it to method but this does not work:

```
val toTypedArray = Arrays.asList("a", "b").toTypedArray()
Paths.get("", toTypedArray) // <- compilation error here
```

No workarounds???

Comment: What do you want to achieve in that?

Comment: Also you should probably use Kotlin's `arrayOf ` instead of `Arrays.asList`

Comment: Is is just example to show the problem. There is no any goals about passing `"a","b"` to `Paths.get` method

Comment: Note that when the function requires non-null primitive type, e.g. `vararg numbers: Int`, you have to use `toIntArray()` instead of `toTypedArray()`.

Comment: @Seaskyways `Arrays.asList(...)` returns a list, so the replacement would be `listOf(...)`

Comment: @RuckusT-Boom that is true, however lists are not usable with the spread operator, only arrays are :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An `Array` can be passed as an`vararg` argument by prepending `*` to it:

```
Paths.get("", *toTypedArray)
```

It’s called **spread operator**, as I already described in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45855062/8073652).

An instance of `List` can be converted to `vararg` as follows:

```
val listAsArr = 
    listOf("a", "b").toTypedArray()
Paths.get("", *listAsArr)
```