# Pass an Array to varargs parameter

Tags: kotlin

If I have a function header like:

```
fun addAttributes(vararg attributes: String) {
  ...
}
```

And I want to pass `attributes` in here:

```
val atts = arrayOf("1", "2", "3")
addAttributes(atts)
```

It gives a compilation error about incompatible types. What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a kotlin collection as varagrs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46418550/how-to-pass-a-kotlin-collection-as-varagrs)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I used the spread operator that basically spreads the elements to make them compatible with `varargs`.

```
addAttributes(*atts)
```

This worked.

Comment: What about the opposite? If I have varargs of string, and I want to pass as an array of strings?

Answer (score 5):

If you have an array then make it like:

```
addAttributes(*arrayVar)
```

If you have a list then in that case:

```
addAttributes(*listVar.toTypedArray())
```

Answer (score 1):

you have two ways:

1. using named parameter
   `addAttributes(attributes = arrayOf("1", "2", "3"))`
2. using spread operator
    `addAttributes(*arrayOf("1", "2", "3"))`