# Is it possible to spread a list inside a list in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

It is possible to do argument unpacking in Kotlin similar to how it is done in Python? E.g.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [*a,4,5,6]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I know that it is possible in Kotlin as follows:

```
>>> listOf(1, 2, 3, *listOf(4,5,6).toTypedArray())
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Feels like there is an easier way in Kotlin. Any ideas?

Comment: If `a = arrayOf(4, 5, 6)`, then `b = listOf(1, 2, 3, *a)` works just fine; see e.g. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The [spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) works on arrays, so you can do this:

```
listOf(1, 2, 3, *(arrayOf(4, 5, 6)))
```

Comment: Any reason why the spread operator is not implemented for other types of collections?

Comment: If you're just adding to the beginning or end, you can also just add the lists: `listOf(1,2,3) + listOf(4,5,6)`

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit of an unfortunate limitation in Kotlin. You can spread lists or whatever with the equivalent operator in Scala, for example.

Comment: @MattR Scala is so much better than Kotlin but Android adopting Kotlin and gradle adopting Kotlin & Groovy effectively killed any chance of Scala becoming the mainstream "modern JVM language". Sad.

Answer (score 4):

The python code can be expressed with the following Kotlin code. As already answered by zsmb13, the operator `*` is also available in Kotlin:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
    val b = arrayOf(*a, 4, 5, 6)
    println(b.contentToString())
}
```

Documentation tells us:

> When we call a vararg-function, we can pass arguments one-by-one, e.g. asList(1, 2, 3), or, **if we already have an array and want to pass its contents to the function, we use the spread operator (prefix the array with *)**:

Also related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46418550/how-to-pass-a-kotlin-collection-as-varagrs/46418689#46418689).