# Compile time error in passing vararg parameter to another function in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-interop

I'm trying to accept a vararg parameter as a function parameter in Kotlin and trying to pass it to another function with vararg parameters. However, it gives me a compile time error in doing so, `type mismatch: inferred type is IntArray but Int was expected`.

**Kotlin:**

```
fun a(vararg a: Int){
   b(a) // type mismatch inferred type is IntArray but Int was expected
}

fun b(vararg b: Int){

}
```

However, if I try the same code in Java, it works.

**Java:**

```
void a(int... a) {
    b(a); // works completely fine
}

void b(int... b) {

}
```

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put a `*` in front of your passed argument (spread operator), i.e.

```
fun a(vararg a: Int){
  // a actually now is of type IntArray
  b(*a) // this will ensure that it can be passed to a vararg method again
}
```

See also: [Kotlin functions reference #varargs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs)

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `a` inside function `a()` has type `IntArray` and needs to be converted to `varargs` again when passed to `b`. This can be done with the "spread operator": `*`

```
fun a(vararg a: Int) {
    b(*a) // spread operator
}
```

It's been described in slightly more detail here before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45855062/8073652

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks so much :)