# JdbcTemplate IN clause in Kotlin

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, jdbctemplate

How is it possible to use the IN clause in Kotlin with JdbcTemplate

```
val days = arrayOf("TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY")
jdbcTemplate.query("select * from days where days not in (?), mapper, days)
```

For the following I get:

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: text = character varying[]
```

Comment: There should be two `?` placeholders, and each day should be bound separately.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
What if the array size varies? How do I pass the arguments then?

Comment: You generate the query dynamically, or you use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate which, AFAIR, supports binding a list for you.

Comment: I can add question marks to the query string dynamically, but I can't think of a way how to add arguments dynamically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854994/kotlin-convert-array-to-java-varargs

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I'm looking for a lot but didn't find any "clean" solution.
It is my solution:

```
@Repository
class AnyRepository (@Autowired var template: JdbcTemplate){
fun anyName(someList: Lis<int>): List<Any> = template.query("SELECT * FROM anyTable WHERE anyTable.id IN (${someList.toString().substring(1, someList.toString().length - 1)})"){ rs, _ -> ... }
}
```

If I find a better solution, I'll post it

Comment: Maybe not beautiful, but just what I needed. Thank you very much - Super Mario.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle the "IN" situations for a JDBC template (in Java or Spring) is to use the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` from Spring.  If you're using environment properties to wire up your data source, one of these should already be available as a bean to autowire in.  If not, you can create one just by passing in the `JdbcTemplate` that you have.

```
val days = arrayOf("TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY")
val namedParamJdbcTemplate = NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate) // or autowired in
// make sure this is not an empty collection! In your example it obviously is not empty.
// but if it is being passed in and could be empty, make sure to not query with it, 
// otherwise the JdbcTemplate will make a where clause of days NOT IN (), which will fail on execution
val paramMap: Map<String, Any?> = mapOf("days" to days) 
namedParamJdbcTemplate.query("select * from days where days not in (:days), paramMap, mapper)
```