# How to convert List to varargs object in Java 8

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

I have a function (`findByNames`) that accepts spreading parameter like the example below :

```
List<Users> findByNames(String... names)
{
  ...
}
```

And as parameter i have a list :

```
List<String> names = asList("john","abraham");
```

So i would like to convert the `names` list to spreading object to use `findByNames` function, is that possible using Java 8 ?
I tried this solution :

```
MapUtils.getMap(names.toArray(new String[names.size()]))
```

but it's not working !

Thank's for you' time.

Comment: Its called [Varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863742/how-to-pass-an-arraylist-to-a-varargs-method-parameter

Comment: @haticeSigirci no is not working, in my case !, did you tried it ?

Comment: The problem seems to be that you say that you want to invoke `findByNames`, but instead of just doing it, you’re invoking `MapUtils.getMap`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Convert the `List<String>` into an array `String[]`:

```
// Java-8(tag in question)
List<Users> users = findByNames(names.toArray(new String[0]));
// Java-11
List<Users> users = findByNames(names.toArray(String[]::new));
```

Comment: in the case of Redis, it's not working for me. my command is `syncCommands.mget(redisKeys.toArray(new String[redisKeys.size()]));` and I get error msg `[Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String`. Any help?

Comment: @roottraveller what type is `redisKeys` in your case? If its `List<String>`, it should just work fine. Are you sure the error is not `mget` accepting a `String` and not `String[]`?

Comment: I fixed it. I just restarted the Redis cluster and it started working.