# How to append an array into an array field in firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

## Question

I have a collection named `Users` with a field named `friendEmails` which is an array that contains Strings.

I have a document with `friendEmails = {joe@gmail.com, dan@gmail.com}`, and I want to append `newEmails = {mat@gmail.com, sharon@gmail.com}` to it.

## Problem

The only options I know for this are:

1. Reading the `friendEmails` array first, then adding the union of it and `newEmails` to the document.
2. Iterating over the elements of `newEmails` (let's and each iteration doing:
   `myCurrentDocumentReference.update(FieldValue.arrayUnion, singleStringElement);`
   (Since `FieldValue.arrayUnion` only lets me pass comma-separated elements, and all I have is an array of elements).

These two options aren't good since the first requires an unnecessary read operation (unnecessary since FireStore seems to "know" how to append items to arrays), and the second requires many write operations.

## The solution I'm looking for

I'd expect Firestore to give me the option to append an entire array, and not just single elements.

Something like this:

```java
ArrayList<String> newEmails = Arrays.asList("mat@gmail.com", "sharon@gmail.com");

void appendNewArray() {
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    firestore.collection("Users").document("userID").update("friendEmails", FieldValue.arrayUnion(newEmails));
}
```

Am I missing something? Wouldn't this be a sensible operation to expect?

How else could I go about performing this action, without all the unnecessary read/write operations?

### Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add multiple items to an array field like this using [FieldValue.arrayUnion()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue#arrayUnion(java.lang.Object...)) as the value of a field update:

```
docRef.update("friendEmails", FieldValue.arrayUnion(email1, email2));
```

If you need to [convert an ArrayList to an array for use with varargs arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863742/how-to-pass-an-arraylist-to-a-varargs-method-parameter):

```
docRef.update("friendEmails", FieldValue.arrayUnion(
    newEmails.toArray(new String[newEmails.size()])
));
```

Comment: My problem is with "unpacking" my existing ```newEmails``` array to pass as arguments for arrayUnion. How would I go about it?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the specific code you're working with, and clarify the question about what isn't working the way you expect with that code.