# Java Spread operator for expanding arrays

Tags: java, operators, operator-keyword

I would like to know if there is something like this in Java:

```
// using JavaScript
let ar = [1,2,3];
Math.max(4, ...ar);
//          ^^^
```

because I have an `EnumSet`, and to have a copy of another `EnumSet` plus another object, i have to do:

```java
var newES = EnumSet.copyOf(someES);
newES.add(p);
doSomething(newES);
```

Where I would like to do something like:

```java
doSomething(EnumSet.of(p, ...someES.toArray()));
```

Comment: Just for clarify: Could you show what the result of `...ar` would be?

Comment: @akuzminykh sure, is the same of writing `Math.max(4, 1, 2, 3);`

Comment: Hm, but how would you write methods for that? Would you write 100 methods to accept 100 different arities? Passing an array is just more practical. You can iterate over an array.

Comment: @akuzminykh `EnumSet.of` already accept a arbitrary number of arguments

Comment: These are related: [Can I pass an array as arguments to a method with variable arguments in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2925153/12323248), [How to pass an ArrayList to a varargs method parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9863742/12323248)

Comment: Also possibly just insert into a list will do.  I think that's all that the JavaScript code is doing.  I notice in the Java example the OP is using sets, not lists, which might be a problem.