# Delete items in batch using a single partition key and multiple corresponding sort keys in dynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have one partition key value and a list of corresponding sort key values for a dynamoDB table, and I'm trying to use batchWriteItem in java to delete them. But it is not working

```
TableWriteItems deleteItems = new TableWriteItems("tableName");
keyList = new ArrayList();
for (String sortKey: sortKeys) {
   keyList.add(partitionKey)
   keyList.add(sortKey)
}
deleteItems.withHashAndRangeKeysToDelete(partKeyField,sortKeyField,keyList)
```

[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/TableWriteItems.html) for doing it this way. But I get the following error:

```
number of hash and range key values must be the same
```

I also tried to add the withHashAndRangeKeysToDelete iteratively to the TableWriteItems object directly, but that didn't work either. So how do I perform this batch delete operation?

Edit:
Based on @luk2302 suggestion, I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863742/how-to-pass-an-arraylist-to-a-varargs-method-parameter) solution to pass the list of hash key and sort keys collected above as a varargs parameter. I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: value type: class [Ljava.lang.String;
```

My code for reference:

```
deleteItems.withHashAndRangeKeysToDelete(partKeyField,sortKeyField, hashRangeList.toArray(new String[0]))
```

Edit2: I mistakenly added an additional param in my code which caused the error. Issue is resolved now so closing the question

Comment: Where is `keyList` defined, are there already objects in it? The internal code only checks `alternatingHashAndRangeKeyValues.length % 2 != 0` and your code should pass that since you always add two entries.

Comment: @luk2302 KeyList is just an empty arrayList that I create prior to the loop. Will edit to add the same. And I checked keyList while debugging and it seems alright

Comment: Actually: the method has a varargs parameter, you need to pass in an array of keys, not a list of keys, the list of keys is considered just one `Object` and you therefore receive that error.